# Efficiently merge / sort / unique large number of text files

Tags: shell, sort, uniq

I am trying a naive:

```
$ cat * | sort -u > /tmp/bla.txt
```

which fails with:

```
-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

So in order to avoid a silly solution like (creates an enormous temporary file):

```
$ find . -type f -exec cat {} >> /tmp/unsorted.txt \;
$ cat /tmp/unsorted.txt | sort -u > /tmp/bla.txt
```

I though I could process files one by one using (this should reduce memory consumption, and be closer to a streaming mechanism):

```
$ cat proc.sh
#!/bin/sh
old=/tmp/old.txt
tmp=/tmp/tmp.txt
cat $old "$1" | sort -u > $tmp
mv $tmp $old
```

Followed then by:

```
$ touch /tmp/old.txt
$ find . -type f -exec /tmp/proc.sh {} \;
```

Is there a simpler more unix-style replacement for: `cat * | sort -u` when the number of files reach `MAX_ARG` ? It feels akward writing a small shell script for such a common task.

Comment: is concatenation needed at all? `sort` does it automatically for multiple file input.. but then `sort -u *` would fail with `Argument list too long` as well I suppose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With GNU `sort`, and a shell where `printf` is built-in (all POSIX-like ones nowadays except some variants of `pdksh`):

```
printf '%s\0' * | sort -u --files0-from=- > output
```

Now, a problem with that is that because the two components of that pipeline are run concurrently and independently, by the time the left one expands the `*` glob, the right one may have created the `output` file already which could cause problem (maybe not with `-u` here) as `output` would be both an input and output file, so you may want to have the output go to another directory (`> ../output` for instance), or make sure the glob doesn't match the output file.

Another way to address it in this instance is to write it:

```
printf '%s\0' * | sort -u --files0-from=- -o output
```

That way, it's `sort` opening `output` for writing and (in my tests), it won't do it before it has received the full list of files (so long after the glob has been expanded). It will also avoid clobbering `output` if none of the input files are readable.

Another way to write it with `zsh` or `bash`

```
sort -u --files0-from=<(printf '%s\0' *) -o output
```

That's using process substitution (where `<(...)` is replaced by a file path that refers to the reading end of the pipe `printf` is writing to). That feature comes from `ksh`, but `ksh` insists in making the expansion of `<(...)` a separate argument to the command so you can't use it with the `--option=<(...)` syntax. It would work with this syntax though:

```
sort -u --files0-from <(printf '%s\0' *) -o output
```

Note that you'll see a difference from approaches that feed the output of `cat` on the files in cases where there are files that don't end in a newline character:

```
$ printf a > a
$ printf b > b
$ printf '%s\0' a b | sort -u --files0-from=-
a
b
$ printf '%s\0' a b | xargs -r0 cat | sort -u
ab
```

Also note that `sort` sorts using the collation algorithm in the locale (`strcollate()`), and `sort -u` reports one of each set of lines that sort the same by that algorithm, not unique lines at byte level. If you only care about lines being unique at byte level and don't care so much about the order they're sorted on, you may want to fix the locale to C where the sorting is based on byte values (`memcmp()`; that would probably speed things up significantly):

```
printf '%s\0' * | LC_ALL=C sort -u --files0-from=- -o output
```

Comment: Feels more natural to write, this also give the opportunity for `sort` to opimize its memory consumption. I still find `printf '%s\0' *` a bit complex to type, though.

Comment: You could use `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0` instead of `printf '%s\0' *`, but I can't claim it's any easier to type.  And the latter is easier to define as an alias, of course!

Comment: @TobySpeight `echo` does have a `-n`, I would have preferred something like `printf -0 %s` this seems a little less low level than `'%s\0'`

Comment: @Toby, `-maxdepth` and `-print0` are GNU extensions (though widely supported these days). With other `find`s (though if you have GNU sort, you're likely to have GNU find as well), you can do `LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune -type f ! -name '.*' -exec printf '%s\0' {} +` (`LC_ALL=C` to still exclude hidden files that contain invalid characters, even with GNU `find`), but that's a bit overkill when you generally have `printf` builtin.

Comment: Agreed, Stéphane - and that last version is clearly no easier for @malat to type!

Comment: @malat, you could always define a `print0` function as `print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@";}` and then `print0 * | sort...`

Answer (score 11):

A simple fix, works at least in Bash, since `printf` is builtin, and the command line argument limits don't apply to it:

```
printf "%s\0" * | xargs -0 cat | sort -u > /tmp/bla.txt
```

(`echo * | xargs` would also work, except for the handling of file names with white space etc.)

Comment: This seems like a better answer than the accepted one, since it doesn't require spawning a separate `cat` process for every file.

Comment: @LarsH, `find -exec {} +` bunches up multiple files per one execution. With `find -exec \;` it would be one cat per file.

Comment: Ah, good to know. (Padding)

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name ".*" -exec cat {} + | sort -u -o /path/to/sorted.txt
```

This will concatenate all non-hidden regular files in the current directory and sort their combined contents (while removing duplicated lines) into the file `/path/to/sorted.txt`.

Comment: I was trying to use only two files at a time to avoid consuming lots of memory (my number of files is rather large). Do you believe `|` will properly chain operations to limit memory usage ?

Comment: @malat `sort` will do an out-of-core sort if memory requirements require it. The left side of the pipeline will consume very little memory in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency is a relative term so you really have to specify which factor you want to minimize; cpu, memory, disk, time etc. For the sake of argument, I am going to assume that you wanted to minimize memory usage and are willing to spend more cpu cycles to achieve that. Solutions such as that given by Stéphane Chazelas work well

```
sort -u --files0-from <(printf '%s\0' *) > ../output
```

but they assume that the individual text files have a high degree of uniqueness to start with. If they don't, ie if after

```
sort -u < sample.txt > sample.srt
```

sample.srt is more than 10% smaller then sample.txt then you will save significant memory by removing the duplicates within files before you merge. You will also save even more memory by not chaining the commands which means the results from different processes do not need to be in memory at the same time.

```
find /somedir -maxdepth 1 type f -exec sort -u -o {} {} \;
sort -u --files0-from <(printf '%s\0' *) > ../output
```

Comment: Memory usage is rarely a concern with `sort` as `sort` resorts to using temporary files when memory usage goes beyond a threshold (usually relatively small). `base64 /dev/urandom | sort -u` will fill up your disk but not use a lot of memory.

Comment: Well, at least it's the case of most `sort` implementations including the original one in Unix v3 in 1972, but apparently not of `busybox sort`. Presumably because that one is intended to run on small systems that don't have permanent storage.

Comment: Note that `yes | sort -u` (all duplicated data) doesn't have to use more than a few bytes of memory let alone disk . But with GNU and Solaris `sort` at least, we see it writing a lot of 2 byte large files in `/tmp` (`y\n` for every few megabytes of input) so it will end-up filling up the disk eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Like @ilkkachu, but the cat(1) is unnecessary:

```
printf "%s\0" * | xargs -0 sort -u
```

Also, If the data is so long maybe you would like to use 
the the sort(1) option  **--parallel**=*N*

When *N* is the number of the CPU's that yours computer has